# iCloud account locked for security reasons

Tags: icloud, password, accounts

I've been having troubles with my iCloud account on my iPhone lately and it recently became really annoying in the sense that i can't do basic things such as updating apps.

Basically i have been told that due to security reasons i had to verify my account. Following that procedure i was given a security phone number entry to get some sort of key to reinitialize my account's password. Here's the twist though : I no longer have that phone number and I don't have any sort of key recovery either. Ultimately i just thought of logging out of the iCloud account - side question here, can anybody tell me what kind of data I exactly lose when I log off the iCloud session on the iphone ? - but then i realised that to logg OFF the account i had to logg IN that same account I do not have the logs of. Am I doing something wrong or is this kind of an irrelevant way to deal with people who lost their logs ?

Thank you for reading/helping out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have to work with Apple to recover your account. Start [here](https://appleid.apple.com/#!&page=signin) and when you get to the two-factor authentication steps, there will be a button with text along the line of "I don't have access to my authentication device" and by clicking this you can start a process which will allow Apple to manually verify your identity and restore control of the account to you.

Comment: Thank you for responding first of all, I did think that would basically be possible, but i've yet to see any button like the one you're describing. I'll post a screenshot of my phone screen hold on

Comment: What happens when you enter the phone number requested (even though you don't have access to it anymore)? I think you have to keep pretending that everything is working until it asks for the code

Comment: Oh no you got me wrong, not only don't I have access to it, i have no idea what number it is, it's not one i recognize at all !

Comment: @pandacoder then I would call Apple support and try to work it out with them. I'm sure you can work with them to help them verify your identity and get your account back. If the technician on the phone can't assist you or won't, have them push you to a manager.

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is the link i get into]

I can't see any button as such anywhere around the website